# Redirect asp.net website not to default.aspx page

Tags: asp.net, redirect

We have a website in asp.net.
How to redirect www.mywebsite.com to www.mywebsite.com/start.aspx and not to www.mywebsite.com/default.aspx. Anyone could please help me on this?

Comment: Default.aspx is the default, which page is given instead depends on the technology you're using to host it (IIS, Visual Studio etc). Personally I wouldn't bother, it means every time you want to deploy you'll have to reset the default.

Comment: The best option, in my opinion, is not show the default document in the URL at all... instead just show `www.mywebsite.com/`. No one wants to look at `start.aspx` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Configuring default document with the IIS Manager.**

Administrative Tools-> IIS Manager -> You Server Name -> Your site name -> Under HTTP features -> Default document -> YourDefaultPage.aspx

See this link to get started with IIS http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-the-iis-manager-in-iis-7-and-iis-8#Home

Comment: You might want to include the IIS option too - depends how it's being hosted

Comment: Site is published in web. Then how could I able to set start.aspx as start page in live?

Comment: then configure default document in the IIS Manager. Check my Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Forms Authentication, within web.config look for this.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name="ADAuthCookie" timeout="60" defaultUrl="~/Dashboard.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Yours may not look dead on to this but you will want to change the defaultUrl to

```
~/Start.aspx
```

If you are not using an Authentication, you can right click the start.aspx within the solution explorer and click "Set as Start Page". This works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't work properly. I usually change Default.aspx to another name or I remove it all together. I'm not sure how your code looks but I hope one of these options help.

Comment: we are not using Form Authentication.

Comment: @Kalaivani take a look at my answer now. I edited in case you weren't using forms authentication.

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe this will send a HTTP redirect back to the browser when the user is not logged in. If this is the case it will double the requests made to your server - better to update the default page in IIS

Comment: Yep, also agree with updating it in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is dealing with Form Authentication, then surely follow humpy's direction. However, in other cases, you can simply click on the file name in Visual Studio and choose the option to "Set As Start Page"